# Why is searching for one of many binaries faster than searching for just one binary using `binary:match` in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I was trying to optimize a parser in Elixir by using `binary:match` instead of pattern matching when I found something strange: `binary:match(Binary, [<<"z">>, <<"y">>])` is several times faster than `binary:match(Binary, <<"z">>)` even when the binary doesn't contain any `y`. Here's a minimal program to reproduce this:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

one(Binary) ->
  binary:match(Binary, <<"z">>).

two(Binary) ->
  binary:match(Binary, [<<"z">>, <<"y">>]).

three(Binary) ->
  binary:match(Binary, [<<"z">>, <<"y">>, <<"x">>]).

main() ->
  As = binary:copy(<<"a">>, 10485760),
  Zs = binary:copy(<<"z">>, 10485760),
  Binary = <<As/binary, Zs/binary>>,
  io:format("~p~n", [timer:tc(?MODULE, one, [Binary])]),
  io:format("~p~n", [timer:tc(?MODULE, two, [Binary])]),
  io:format("~p~n", [timer:tc(?MODULE, three, [Binary])]).
```

And here's the output on a fairly fast OSX system:

```
{62556,{10485760,1}}
{18272,{10485760,1}}
{18558,{10485760,1}}
```

and on a not so fast Linux VPS:

```
{130249,{10485760,1}}
{39296,{10485760,1}}
{40805,{10485760,1}}
```

So, for a binary containing 10MB of `a` followed by 10MB of `z`, searching for `["z", "y"]` or `["z", "y", "x"]` takes about 30% of the time than searching for just `"z"`, even though the result is the same, as the binary does not contain any `y` or `x`. I can reproduce this even if I reorder the calls.

So my question is why does this happen and how can I make the single binary search faster?

(I'm running `Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0.2]`.)

Comment: The function `do_binary_match_compile` in `erl_bif_binary.c` seems to select different algorithms depending on whether there's one "word" or several in the pattern; see [the code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/a0abdb8631d7bd7a154023950ccdcbf09c85b92d/erts/emulator/beam/erl_bif_binary.c#L952-L999). For one word, it uses Boyer-Moore, and for several, it uses Aho-Corasick. Not sure why that makes such a difference, though...

Answer (score 1):

The obvious workaround for speeding up search for a single binary is searching for `[<<"z">>, <<"z">>]` (I've checked that it works and that searching for `[<<"z">>]` doesn't). No idea for why it happens, though.